# dry run of nump's vectorize

Tags: numpy, vectorization, dry-run

When I run a function, which is vectorized with numpy it is always executed once more than I would expect. Thus, before the actual calling starts, there seems to be a dry run. Recently, I run into trouble because of this. See the following minimal example:

```
import numpy as np

class PERSON:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

class TIME:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ages = np.array([0,0])

    def init_persons(self):
        vec_init_persons = np.vectorize(self.__scalar_init_person)
        self.persons = vec_init_persons(self.ages)

    def __scalar_init_person(self, age):
        return PERSON(age)

    def let_time_pass(self):
        vec_let_time_pass = np.vectorize(self.__scalar_let_time_pass)
        vec_let_time_pass(self.persons)

    def __scalar_let_time_pass(self, person):
        person.age += 1

time = TIME()
time.init_persons()
time.let_time_pass()

print("Age of person 1: {}".format(time.persons[0].age)) # output is 2 not 1!
print("Age of person 2: {}".format(time.persons[1].age)) # output is 1
```

Normally, I would have guessed, the age of both persons is 1.
So my questions are:

1. Does anybody now the purpose of this dry run? For me I just seems to be a source of potential trouble.
2. What is the pythonic way to deal with a problem, illustrated by the example?

Comment: `np.vectorize` makes one calculation to determine the `dtype` of the result.  I think that's you are calling a dry-run.  To avoid that use `otypes`.  There may also be a `caching` option.  In any case, `vectorize` is meant to be a convenience in cases where you can't use "real" numpy vectorization.  It is not a performance tool.  Read the docs in full.

Comment: Sometimes it's a good idea to have the 'vectorized' function print its argument, so you have a clearer idea of how `np.vectorize` ends up calling it.  `np.vectorize` does not compile your function.  It's just another way of iterating through the inputs.

Comment: Probably the best approach is just not to use `np.vectorize`

Answer (score 1):

from the docs

> The data type of the output of `vectorized` is determined by calling
> the function with the first element of the input.  This can be avoided
> by specifying the `otypes` argument.

> The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
> performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Comment: Thanks, hpaulj for the first comment! Using the option "cache = True" is exately what I want. At a matter of fact, I do not see any drawbacks of always using "cache = True". Do you know what's the reason for not setting the default of cache to True?

Comment: It says the `cache` slows the code, doesn't it? `vectorize` is already slow.  I think `otypes` is better.  People have gotten bit by the auto dtype (e.g. expecting floats but getting int because the trial run returns 0).  Here simple iteration on `ages` is better.